# Flex: Controlling browser statusbar

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

My application has to call server several times per one second (to check if position on board changed or not). I didn't find anything better for now then implement a timer and call server so often to check if something was updated (actually only small amount of data is sent so I think nothing bad will happen). Anyway some browsers like firefox, shows in status line something like "Transferring data...", and the text which flicker there is annoying.
I wonder if there is a way to control the status line from the flex application?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing you can use out-of-the-box in Flex (or Flash, for that matter) to control the status bar, you need to use JavaScript for that. Communicating Flash and JS is easy, just take a look to ExternalInterface.

Problem is this never ending "Transferring data" message in Firefox, it's annoying as hell, and I still haven't found how to get rid of it. I was once told sending some specific headers would do the trick, but just didn't fully work for me at that time.

I'd love to hear a definitive answer on this one as well.

Juan

Comment: Yeah, using Javascript with Flex isn't that difficult. I can say from my experience I had to send a captured image from flex to javascript and it was quite easy to do.

Comment: Maybe you can show me an example? Or even point where to start reading please :)

Comment: Here's is the reference for [url=http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html]ExternalInterface[/url]